# HTTP request in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rest

i want to create class to handle all http request as the following

inside viewController i want to call function from ServiceClass(class that handle all http requests) that handle a specific http request and inside this function i will handle result and then move to any another viewController.
i'm beginner in IOS so i don't know if there better idea.

Edite:
My Question "how to move from ServiceClass to any another viewController while ServiceClass doesn't have any View.

Comment: Great idea, but what is your question?

Comment: i can't navigate from ServiceClass to any anther viewController as ServiceClass doesn't extent UIViewController

Comment: then why don't u implement the transition inside the function that calls ServiceClass methods?

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: @RinaLiu can you give me example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a singleton class call it whatever you like for instance HTTPService. This is a Swift file by the way not a viewController class. Once you have figured out how to create a singleton add the functions for NSURLSession to it and when you have completed the task of connecting to your server create a completion block (closure) which will have a reference to the response from your server. You can then use this HTTPService class in any viewController by creating a reference to it and you will be able to access the completion handler and the response you got from your HTTPService singleton class anywhere in your app. This is just one way. And there are many subjects you will need to cover to get this under you belt. If this is too much check Alamofire which will do most of this for you here [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Comment: Not sure why I am downvoted! U need a completion handler and then you'll be able to access it whenever you like

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use Alamofire library. Otherwise create singleton class with HTTP requests. Singleton class represent single instance for class and access in any viewcontroller.